# Do iOS web apps support the new “fast tap” behavior?

Tags: iphone-standalone-web-app

I’m writing a web app that is intended to be used through a home-screen shortcut under iOS. I added the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                               initial-scale=1,
                               user-scalable=no"/>
```

to take advantage of the new [fast tap](https://webkit.org/blog/5610/more-responsive-tapping-on-ios/) behavior. This works great within Safari but when I add the app to my home screen and use it that way I get the older “slow tap” behavior. I tried adding the CSS

```
body {
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

but that didn’t work either.

Is the new fast tap behavior simply not supported for this kind of web app?

Answer (score 1):

Use [touch-action](https://www.npmjs.com/package/touch-action) for this. When touch-action property is not supported, it asynchronously downloads [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) from CDN and use FastClick.attach(document.body) as polyfill.